# How do I correct errors on my 'save to file' button in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;


private void btnFileSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\CedulaList.txt"));

                  for (int i = 0 ; i < tableCedula.getRowCount(); i++)
                  {

                    for(int j = 0 ; j < tableCedula.getColumnCount();j++)
                    {
                        bfw.newLine();
                        bfw.write((String)(tableCedula.getValueAt(i,j)));
                        bfw.write("\t");;
                    }
                  }
                  bfw.close();



}
```

i do not seem to grasp how to solve this.. the error says, "unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.

Convert to try-with-resources."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to throws/try-catch as:

```
private void btnFileSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                            
   try{
      BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\CedulaList.txt"));

              for (int i = 0 ; i < tableCedula.getRowCount(); i++)
              {

                for(int j = 0 ; j < tableCedula.getColumnCount();j++)
                {
                    bfw.newLine();
                    bfw.write((String)(tableCedula.getValueAt(i,j)));
                    bfw.write("\t");;
                }
              }
   }catch(Exception ex){

   }finally{
      if(bfw != null){
         bfw.close();
      }
   }    
}
```

Comment: hi. thank you for your code. i used it and it only creates the save file. but inside the text file, there is nothing on it.

Comment: @theblackaccord You 're welcome. I think you are not writing any data into the file. Please check whether 'tableCedula.getValueAt(i,j)' is giving any data or not. And, let me know if you are facing any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `throws`clause to the method signature

```
private void btnFileSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) throws IOException {
```

or use a `try catch` block

```
private void btnFileSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
   try {
    BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\CedulaList.txt"));

                  for (int i = 0 ; i < tableCedula.getRowCount(); i++)
                  {

                    for(int j = 0 ; j < tableCedula.getColumnCount();j++)
                    {
                        bfw.newLine();
                        bfw.write((String)(tableCedula.getValueAt(i,j)));
                        bfw.write("\t");;
                    }
                  }
                  bfw.close();
    } catch(IOException e){
         //Handle the exception
    }


}
```

Comment: hi. thank you for your help. just where do i add the throws exception code? i am using the jframe editor and i cannot edit the code in the private void area. thanks.

Comment: i can only click the save to file button and go to properties and edit it from there. i do not know where to put the 'throws Exception' though

Comment: @theblackaccord Can you try the second solution?

Comment: yes. it worked. all i need to do now is to add all the data entered in jtable to the textfile. thank you.

Comment: when i click on the button, it only creates the text file, but with nothing on it.

Comment: @theblackaccord try to debug your code to see whats happend